# InnerException : Table 'xxx.aspnetusers' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API project which uses Entity Framework 6.1.1 and MySQL 6.9.5.0. When I call  /api/Account/Register using DHC, the code breaks at

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

in the AccountController and I get an InnerException which says

```
Table 'xxx.aspnetusers' doesn't exist
```

Here are pieces of my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ClockitDb" connectionString="Data Source=ClockitDb;port=3306;Initial Catalog=ClockitDb;Server=localhost;user id=root;password=m916600026;"
  providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<!-- Some code-->

<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers> 
</entityFramework>

<!-- Some code-->

<system.web>

<authentication mode="Forms" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
    <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
    <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<siteMap defaultProvider="MySqlSiteMapProvider">
  <providers>
    <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
    <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
<webParts>

<personalization defaultProvider="MySQLPersonalizationProvider">
    <providers>
      <remove name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" />
      <add name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" type="MySql.Web.Personalization.MySqlPersonalizationProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </personalization>
</webParts>
```

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Comment: Have you created the tables and stored procs for the identity infrastructure in your MySQL database?

Comment: The following tables are auto generated with SQL as soon as the API is called for the first time. 
AspNetRoles,
AspNetUserClaims,
AspNetLogins,
AspNetRoles,
AspNetUsers. 

Shouldn't it be the same with MySQL also?

Comment: I think you still need to use the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` and perhaps do some other configuration.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-simple-membership-tutorial-creating.html

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem .
I followed the following tutorial and it worked
[How to set up application using ASP.NET Identity with MySQL Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w)

It is important that you follow all the steps of the tutorial,even the migration setup, otherwise it gives the same error.

Comment: It runs but membership and profile tables are not created.

Answer (score 1):

The exception clearly states that aspnetusers is missing from your database. However, on more findings, I think you would like to go through this answer from asp.net forum.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1977214.aspx?Mvc+5+Identity+Error+Invalid+object+name+dbo+AspNetUsers

For Role,Membership Provider, asp.net [entire asp.net stack/webapi included] with mysql, you need to have that providers specific to mysql in place. For this, you can refer to
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117157/Setting-up-MySql-Membership-with-Visual-Studio

Let me know, if this solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I tried following the instructions on

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117157/Setting-up-MySql-Membership-with-Visual-Studio.

When I launch the security tab in ASP Website administration tool, I get an error saying

```
The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (C:\Users\Jaseem Abbas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MySQLSample1\MySQLSample1\web.config line 33).
```

My line 33 in web config starts as

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider"
         type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,
         MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, 
         Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
         connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/"
         autogenerateschema="true" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>ASP
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLProfileProvider, 
         MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, 
         Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
         name="MySqlProfileProvider"
         applicationName="/"
         connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
         autogenerateschema="true" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
         applicationName="/"
         name="MySqlRoleProvider"
         type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, 
         MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, 
         Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
         autogenerateschema="true" />
  </providers>
```

Comment: Please check whether you have "MySql.Data" assembly in your reference folder or now. If it is there then check the version and try to match it with web.config version. Hope this helps.